# Proving if linear functions are isometries

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry

I have a difeomorfism between two spaces $f:M\rightarrow S$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, that is defined by a 3 x 3 matrix. I have to determine that this difeomorfism is not an isometry. Our method for proving that a difeomorfism is not an isometry is very long but is meant for a standard difeomorfism. I seem to remember that is $\mathbb{R}^2$, the determinant of the matrix acted as a scale factor; can the same be said in $\mathbb{R}^3$? In other words, if the matrix has a determinant not equal to 1, can I say, without further calculation that it is not an isometry, and similarly, if the determinant is 1 (or maybe -1), can I say that it must be an isometry?

Many thanks :)

Comment: What are these spaces? Are they curves, surfaces, or open subsets of $\Bbb R^3$? You need to look at how $f$ acts on $M$, not on all of $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, they are differentiable surfaces in R3

Comment: Then you need to look at the action of the matrix on the tangent spaces of the surface. The determinant is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the determinant of a matrix is not $+1$ *or* $-1$, it is definitely not an isometry--because isometries would preserve lengths, and hence volumes. (However, they may reverse orientation, and so $-1$ is allowed!)

But there are matrices with determinant 1 that are not isometries! Take the linear map which scales the $x$-axis up by a factor of 4, and scales both $y$-- and $z$-axes down by a factor of 2. This has a total determinant of $4 \cdot (1/2) \cdot (1/2) = 1,$ but is not an isometry.

To check if a matrix is an isometry, you need the columns to form an orthonormal basis--so all have norm 1 and are mutually orthogonal.

Comment: Is it clear that the spaces are all of $\Bbb R^3$?